# "Couldn't match expected type with actual type" error when using Codec.BMP

Tags: haskell

I have a very little experience in Haskell and I want to write a simple ray tracer for practice. Because I didn't want to use GUI tools like wxHaskell (I think it'll take a lot of time to learn how to use them), I decided to simply save the output image to BMP file. But I have a problem here:

```hs
module Main where

import Codec.BMP
import qualified Data.ByteString as BS

main = do
  Right bmp <- readBMP "grass.bmp"
  BS.putStrLn $ BS.take 4 $ unpackBMPToRGBA32 bmp
```

Here I just want to take first pixel of the image and print its RGBA values. But I get an error saying

```
Couldn't match expected type `BS.ByteString'
            with actual type `bytestring-0.9.2.1:Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString'
In the return type of a call of `unpackBMPToRGBA32'
In the second argument of `($)', namely `unpackBMPToRGBA32 bmp'
In the second argument of `($)', namely
  `BS.take 4 $ unpackBMPToRGBA32 bmp'
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I take the pixels of the image and print their values?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have two `bytestring` packages installed, so `unpackBMPToRGBA32` return `ByteString` from `bytestring-0.9.2.1`, and `BS.putStrLn` expects `ByteString` from other version.

Try `ghc-pkg list bytestring` to list all `bytestring` versions installed.

And the solution could be

- unregister one of them with `ghc-pkg unregister bytestring-<version>`
- hide one of them when building: `ghc --make -hide-package bytestring-<version>`

Comment: Yeah, it works! Thanks, this `-hide-package` option is really useful!

Comment: Thanks, Yuras.   If you want to use -hide-package with runhaskell (rather than building), you'll need the following invocation:

`runhaskell -hide-package --ghc-arg=bytestring-<version> Main.hs`