# Puzzling Data.Encoding Error

Tags: haskell, encoding, character-encoding

I am trying to use a decoder from `Data.Encoding` on some text that I'm not sure is encoded correctly.  When I attempt to load the following code into haskell:

```
import Data.Encoding (DynEncoding,decodeLazyByteStringExplicit,encodingFromStringExplicit)
{- ...more imports ... -}
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as B (ByteString,takeWhile)

{- ... more code ... -}
decodeMyString :: Encoding enc => B.ByteString -> enc -> Either String String
decodeMyString str decoder = case (decodeLazyByteStringExplicit decoder str) of
    Left s -> Left $ show s
    Right decoded -> Right decoder
```

I get the following error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `bytestring-0.10.0.2:Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString'
            with actual type `B.ByteString'
In the second argument of `decodeLazyByteStringExplicit', namely
  `str'
In the expression: (decodeLazyByteStringExplicit decoder str)
In the expression:
  case (decodeLazyByteStringExplicit decoder str) of {
    Left s -> Left $ show s
    Right decoded -> Right decoded }
```

Can anyone explain why?  I have the latest versions of the libraries `bytestring` (10.4) and `encoding` (0.7).  But it should not matter, because [`encoding's hackage page`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/encoding) does not specify a required version of bytestring.

At this point, I'm almost tempted to write my own set of decoders for non-unicode encodings of `bytestrings` to convert them into utf-whatever bytestrings and use `Data.Text.Encoding`  but I shouldn't have to given the existence of `Data.Encoding`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a common problem when two different packages were assembled with different versions of the same library (ByteString in this case). A solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576817/couldnt-match-expected-type-with-actual-type-error-when-using-codec-bmp).

Comment: Unfortunately, since this code forms part of a parser, hiding the newer version of bytestring breaks dependencies of the parser itself (parsec), and hiding the older one raises the same error.  Is there any other way around this?

Comment: @MikeMenzel Reinstall both packages with a common version of bytestring. For example, `cabal install --reinstall parsec yourotherpackage`.