# Type mismatch error in making HTTP request

Tags: haskell, http-conduit

Trying to make a HTTP request, I got the error:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Network.HTTP.Conduit -- the main module

-- The streaming interface uses conduits
import Data.Conduit
import Data.Conduit.Binary (sinkFile)

import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as L
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (liftIO)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    simpleHttp "http://www.example.com/foo.txt" >>= L.writeFile "foo.txt"
```

The error is:

```
Couldn't match type `L.ByteString'
                  with `bytestring-0.10.0.2:Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString'
    Expected type: bytestring-0.10.0.2:Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString
                   -> IO ()
      Actual type: L.ByteString -> IO ()
    In the return type of a call of `L.writeFile'
    In the second argument of `(>>=)', namely `L.writeFile "foo.txt"'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      simpleHttp "http://www.example.com/foo.txt"
      >>= L.writeFile "foo.txt"
```

I can't figure out how to solve it because the text of the error doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two conflicting versions on `bytestring` package. Try `ghc-pkg list bytestring`. I'd suggest you to cabalize your code and use cabal sandbox.

See also ["Couldn't match expected type with actual type" error when using Codec.BMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576817/couldnt-match-expected-type-with-actual-type-error-when-using-codec-bmp/12577025#12577025)

BTW, the error message should be better in `ghc-7.8`, see https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/8278

Comment: +1 for cabal sandbox. Use `cabal sandbox init` in your project directory to set up

Comment: `$ ghc-pkg list bytestring
/usr/local/Cellar/ghc/7.6.3_2/lib/ghc-7.6.3/package.conf.d
   bytestring-0.10.0.2
/Users/alex/.ghc/x86_64-darwin-7.6.3/package.conf.d
   bytestring-0.10.4.0` -- what's next?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp see the other answer I linked. It contains two options how to fix that issue. But nowadays `cabal` is the preferred way.

Comment: I fixed it. But how did you realize that `You have two conflicting versions ...`, the error messages didn't imply that, did they?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp They did. Note that the expected type is fully qualified, including package version. `ghc` omits package name in error massages unless it is ambiguous.

Comment: by the way, `$ cabal sandbox init =>
cabal: unrecognised command: sandbox (try --help)`