# Haskell ByteString type error

Tags: haskell, pcap, bytestring

It is the first time I use ByteStrings and the first time I ever see a *pcap* file.
I am basically trying to *efficiently* read the pcap file with ByteStrings and print its content on screen.
I am using the [Network.Pcap library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pcap-0.2/docs/Network-Pcap.html#t%3ACallback) to read the file. The *ByteString variant* can be found here: [Network.Pcap ByteString](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pcap-0.4.5/docs/Network-Pcap.html#1). To make things easy I want just to print the *first* line of the file so my code looks like this:

```
1 import qualified Data.ByteString as B

2 printIt :: PktHdr -> B.ByteString -> IO ()
3 printIt ph bytep = do
4    print $ hdrCaptureLength ph  -- not important
5    print $ bytep

6 main = do
7    f <- openOffline "file.pcap"
8    dispatchBS f (1) printIt
```

where `printIt` is the *callbackBS* function that operates on the body of the file.

The compiler complains with this message:

```
Couldn't match type ‘B.ByteString’
              with ‘bytestring-0.10.4.0:Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString’
NB: ‘B.ByteString’
      is defined in ‘Data.ByteString.Internal’
          in package ‘bytestring-0.10.4.1’
    ‘bytestring-0.10.4.0:Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString’
      is defined in ‘Data.ByteString.Internal’
          in package ‘bytestring-0.10.4.0’
Expected type: CallbackBS
  Actual type: PktHdr -> B.ByteString -> IO ()
In the third argument of ‘dispatchBS’, namely ‘printIt’
In a stmt of a 'do' block: dispatchBS f (1) printIt
```

What I understand is that for the compiler, the callbackBS function must have type: `PktHdr -> ByteString -> IO ()`, while at line **2** the types is `PktHdr ->`**B.**`ByteString -> IO ()`.
However I can not simply use the type ByteString because then I would incur in conflicts with functions defined in the prelude for normal lists.
Do you have any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Couldn't match expected type with actual type" error when using Codec.BMP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576817/couldnt-match-expected-type-with-actual-type-error-when-using-codec-bmp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiler is trying to tell you that you are using two different `bytestring` packages. For the details and a solution see here: ["Couldn't match expected type with actual type" error when using Codec.BMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576817/couldnt-match-expected-type-with-actual-type-error-when-using-codec-bmp/12577025#12577025)

Comment: @Filippo you probably should cabalize your code to prevent such issues. For example see https://wiki.haskell.org/How_to_write_a_Haskell_program

Comment: If now I use the Lazy version of ByteStrings (`import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as B  
`)it does not work anymore and I get a similar error as before: `Couldn't match type ‘B.ByteString’
                  with ‘Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString’
    NB: ‘B.ByteString’ is defined in ‘Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal’
        ‘Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString’
          is defined in ‘Data.ByteString.Internal’`

Comment: That's a different error. It's because lazy and strict bytestrings aren't the same type. You need to convert between them. I wrote a [tutorial on bytestrings](https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/tekul/bytestring-bits-and-pieces) a while back which you might want to take a look at.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was really helpful. Cannot believe FPComplete people are answering my stupid question. Many thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm not an FPComplete person though :). Anyone can create an account and post content. You can also run the code in-place by clicking the little play icon in the top right corner, which is nice.